# Why do I need to redirect in order to send the external OAuth2 authentication token to the client?

Tags: authentication, oauth

In an OAuth2 scenario:

- user confirmed his identity, allows the app to access his details
- server got the external access token

I intend to respond directly with a `local access token` as opposed to redirecting to a Uri containing the `external access token` fragment.

Is there a point in obtaining local access token in a separate request, based on the external token?

Is there something more than meets the eye in a redirect when returning a security token to the user?